# Calculating inventory cost in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.  One holds the quantity for a specific unit.  The other holds the quantities, dates and costs when these units historically arrived.

So in my first table, I would say UNIT "ABC" has a quantity of 50

In the second table, I would have data that looks like this:

```
Unit   Date arrived   Quantity   Cost
----   ------------   --------   -----
ABC       11/1            100    $3.00
ABC       11/4             15    $5.00
ABC       11/5             25    $6.00
```

So in this example, I would need to figure the value of the 50 items based on a first in, first out system.  The math would look like this for the 50 items:

```
25 x $6.00
15 x $5.00
10 x $3.00
```

The total value for this item would be $255.00

So I need to do this with about 300,000 items and I need an "easy button".  Currently using MS Access & SQL to mine my data.  So any solution relevant to either of those platforms would be great.

Comment: If you want FIFO cost of 50 "ABC" items, based on data in the second table, you would get $3.00 from the first row.  If you had 110 "ABC" items, the FIFO unit cost would be $350/110.  Is this what you need?  You asked for "first in, first out" but you only have "in".

Comment: I figured out what FIFO means in this context (I think).  In effect, the stock is loaded in date order (FI) but the assumption is that anything left on the shelf is only there because any items pulled - would have been pulled from the earliest deliveries (FO). So the value of any stock held would be worked out from the latest price on the latest delivery - and then working backwards until what's in stock has been valued.  It's obviously a long time since I've written a stock control system...

Comment: @dav1dsm1th yes, that makes much more sense, and fits the posted details. I guess it shows it's been even longer since I worked on costing inventory, lol

Comment: Are you calculating current value, with changing inventory levels?  If so, are items tracked by lot?  If YES and NO, perhaps one can assume the first in will be the first removed.  If YES and YES, your method becomes more complex.  Your post does not raise these issues but they are typical for inventory valuation.

Answer (score 2):

This:-

```
select s.unit, dv.cost_2d+((s.quantity-dv.quantity_2d)*dv.cost) as valuation
from (
    select 
        d.*, 
        isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) as quantity_2d,
        isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity*csq.cost) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) as cost_2d
    from #delivery d

    -- possible optimization - reduces the number of rows
    -- if we have enough to calculate value of stock held

    --join #stock s on s.unit=d.unit
    --and isnull((
    --    select sum(csq.quantity)
    --    from #delivery csq
    --    where csq.unit=d.unit 
    --        and csq.arrived>d.arrived
    --    ),0)<=s.quantity 

    -- you'd need to test if it helps/hinders with your dataset/schema

) as dv
join #stock s on s.unit=dv.unit
where dv.quantity+dv.quantity_2d>=s.quantity 
    and dv.quantity_2d<s.quantity
```

produces:-

```
unit    valuation
abc     255.00
```

if fed from:-

```
create table #stock (
    unit varchar(10),
    quantity int
)

create table #delivery (
    unit varchar(10),
    arrived date,
    quantity int,
    cost money
)

insert into #stock values ('abc',50)
insert into #delivery values ('abc','2013-11-01',100,3)
insert into #delivery values ('abc','2013-11-04',15,5)
insert into #delivery values ('abc','2013-11-05',25,6)
```

-----------UPDATE-----------------------------------

Here's another version that may or may not run quicker - depending on your dataset/schema:-

```
select dv.unit, dv.cost_2d+((dv.instock-dv.quantity_2d)*dv.cost) as valuation
from (
    select 
        d.*, 
        isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) as quantity_2d,
        isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity*csq.cost) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) as cost_2d,
        s.quantity as instock
    from #delivery d
    join #stock s on s.unit=d.unit
    and s.quantity between isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) and isnull((
            select sum(csq.quantity) 
            from #delivery csq 
            where csq.unit=d.unit 
                and csq.arrived>d.arrived
        ),0) + d.quantity
) as dv
```

Comment: I added a second optimization at the bottom of my answer.  This produces the same results and may allow the query to run more efficiently in OPs environment (my test data is too small to measure any advantage/disadvantage of the code).

Comment: Should be able to improve on this and calculate out valuation within the derived table - to simply the code further (I may come back to this if OP has performance problems).

Comment: Your second set of code ran perfectly (and quickly).  Brilliant.

Comment: That's great to hear.  The d.* should really be expanded to just the field list that's required - to give the optimizer the best opportunity to make the code run as efficiently as possible (you should never have *'s in production code - except in `EXISTS`).  Some appropriate indexes never do any harm...

Comment: Has this answered your question?